# Show the correct error validation messages

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, error-handling, controller

I have a page with 2 forms on it: a registration form and a login form. Each form has a submit button. Now I'm validating both forms, but for example if I press the submit button of the registration form I'd like only to show the error messages of the registration form and not of the login form. At the moment both error message are being shown. Is there a way around this?

```
<div class="grid-container">

    <div class="grid-50 login">
        <h3>Inloggen</h3>
        <?php

            $loginEmail = array('placeholder' => "Email", 'name' => "loginEmail");
            $loginPassword = array('placeholder' => "Wachtwoord", 'name' => "loginPassword");
            $loginSubmit = array('name' => "loginSubmit", 'class' => "btn", 'value' => "Inloggen");
            $loginForgot = array('name' => "loginForgot", 'class' => "link", 'value' => "Wachtwoord vergeten?");

            echo form_open('login/inloggen', array('class' => 'grid-100 formc'));
            echo form_input($loginEmail);
            echo form_password($loginPassword);
            echo form_submit($loginSubmit);
            echo form_submit($loginForgot);
            echo form_close();
        ?>
        <?php echo validation_errors('<p class="error">');?>
    </div>



    <div class="grid-50 login">
        <h3>Registreren</h3>

        <?php

            $registerName = array('placeholder' => "Naam", 'name' => "registerName");
            $registerEmail = array('placeholder' => "Email", 'name' => "registerEmail");
            $registerPassword = array(  'placeholder' => "Wachtwoord", 'name' => "registerPassword");


    $registerSubmit = array('name' => "registerSubmit", 'class' => "btn", 'value' => "Registreer");

        echo form_open('login/register');
        echo form_input($registerName, set_value('registerName'));
        echo form_input($registerEmail, set_value('registerEmail'));
        echo form_password($registerPassword);
        echo form_submit($registerSubmit);
        echo form_close();
    ?>

    <?php echo validation_errors('<p class="error">');?>
</div>
```

Validation in the controller

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('registerEmail', 'Email verkeerd', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('registerPassword', 'Password te kort', 'trim|required|min_length[4]');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it would be nicer if you create different rules for the `login` and for you're `registration`.

how?

create a `Form_validation.php` file on `application/libraries`

inside specify the rules for you're login and `register` example

```
$config = array(
  'login_validation_rules'=>array(
        array(
        'field' => 'username',
        'label' => 'The User Name',
        'rules' => 'required'
    ),
        array(
        'field' => 'password',
        'label' => 'The Password',
        'rules' => 'required'
    )

   ),
   'registration_validation_rules'=>array(
        array(
        'field' => 'email',
        'label' => 'The Email',
        'rules' => 'required|valid_email'
    ),
        array(
        'field' => 'firstname',
        'label' => 'The Firstname',
        'rules' => 'required'
    )
   )
 );
```

Then on you're `controller` you can catch what form they are submitting and what validation rules to use example

```
if($this->input->post('registerSubmit'))
{
  if($this->form_validation->run('registration_validation_rules') == FALSE)
  {
   //error
  }else{
   //good
  }
}elseif($this->input->post('loginSubmit')){
  if($this->form_validation->run('login_validation_rules') == FALSE)
  {
   //error
  }else{
   //good
  }
}
```

At the same time you're controller will not be cluttered with rules. makes reading easier you can read more of this on the [Codigniter manual - validation config file](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#savingtoconfig)

Comment: I have changed everything just like you suggested. But I'm still getting the error messages of the registration under neath the login form with `<?php echo validation_errors('<p class="error">');?>`

Answer (score 0):

Do you use two submit in one page? try to make one to submit through javascript or jquery
be cause when you submit the submit it submit the whole page in some browsers

also try this show validate error for each fields

```
 <?=form_error('loginEmail')?>

 <?=form_error('registerPassword')?>
```